# Where is my Steam inventory?

Tags: steam

I haven't been logged into Steam much recently, but I've just logged into it now and had the following bit of toast pop up in the corner:

[image]

I wasn't even aware that there was an inventory on the Steam platform - what is it, where is it, and what can be stored in it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From either the Steam Store or the Steam interface, click the "Community" link, and you'll be taken you your "Steam feed."  From here, the inventory link is on the right hand column, as shown below:

[image]

Note that you might have to change the tab, or check your Gifts in order to see everything there is to see in your inventory.  The default is to display your TF2 items, whereas game gifts and so forth will show up in different parts of the interface:

[image]

Comment: Curse you, I was imgur-ing a picture without a nasty freehand circle around it! *fistshake*

Comment: Freehand circles FTW!

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to get there is in the "My Profile" menu.

[image: My Profile > My Inventory]

Comment: +1 This is a lot faster then going through Community, the Community page lags like hell for me.