# How do I download a game I traded for?

Tags: steam

I traded a player in Team Fortress 2 for a copy of DOTA 2. However, I don't know what to do next.

Where do I download the game from? This is a bit confusing as this is my first time trading with someone for a game.

Comment: Try looking in your [Steam Inventory](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/90116/27134) - it should be there, you will need to redeem it which will add it to your library and then you can download it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[How do I use a Steam gift given to me by a friend?](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?p_faqid=549#gifts-use)

Essentially, as per what @pixel said, check both your inventory or your gift page.  If you were trading, then you should find your game within your inventory, and if it was a gift, you should find it within your gift page.

When you are in your [inventory](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/90116/where-is-my-steam-inventory?lq=1), click on the Steam tab.  That should bring up your "games" received via trade.  Click on the game you received, and there should be a button that says "add to library".

Once you finish downloading, your game is ready! Note, you cannot trade that game out once you have added it to your library. Steam has strict rules about sharing/trading games.